# D3.js replace points in svg path

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have pre-rendered curved svg paths with points looking like this

```
d="M 547, 699 C 547, 759 347, 236, 347, 296"
```

What I need, is a way to make all those lines straight, basically connecting first and last point directly, like that

```
d="M 547, 699, 347, 296"
```

I'm using D3 to modify svg elements. I've tried to read current d attribute using attr("d"), then using regex to change it to second format and set it back to node using attr("d", newPath), but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

edit:
the code I've tried for replacing path points is like this:

```
var d = d3.select(".nodes-path").attr("d");
d = d.replace(/\D/g, ",");
var dArray = d.split(",");
var newPath = "M " +
      dArray[0] +
      ", " +
      dArray[1] +
      ", " + //now I know it should be ", L " on this line
      dArray[dArray.length - 2] +
      ", " +
      dArray[dArray.length - 1];
d3.select(".nodes-path").attr("d", newPath);
```

And path looks like this:

```
<path d="M 547, 502 C 547, 562 347, 236, 347, 296" class="nodes-path"></path>
```

But it doesn't change d attribute in path. I also need a way to make it in a loop (selecting works now, because I have only one path, but there will be more), probably using selectAll, but dunno how can I get attribute and then set it back with adjustments that way.

edit2: but if I do something like that:

```
d3.select(".canvas-layer")
      .append("g")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", "M 547, 502 L 347, 296")
      .attr("class", "nodes-path");
```

it shows two paths, one curved, one straight. So the problem is to read from and set attribute d of rendered path. How to do it?

Comment: You need to use the jQuery/`querySelector`/CSS syntax for selecting your path: `d3.select(".nodes-path")`. Note the dot in front

Comment: unfortunately, jQuery is not an option :(

Comment: I mean that the style is the same, not that you should use jQuery. Just add a period in front of the selector

Comment: Uh, I get you, thing is, I have this dot, dunno why it disappeared when I copied, must have deleted it by accident when I adjusted few things to make this more readable. But it still doesn't work

Comment: You need to add it in both places, also `d3.select(".nodes-path").attr("d", newPath);`

Comment: yes, in my actual code there are dots, I just renamed classes here to make it more readable and forgot to place them in post

Comment: Ok, sorry to bug you. It's one of the most common sources of errors on SO

Comment: Thing is, I suspect it's more tricky to modify d attribute. If I just append svg with new path, it's fine (except for displaying two paths, which is undesirable of course), but for some reason reading from existing d attribute returns nothing (console shows empty line if i try to log it) and setting it back does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put your code into a snippet, it just updates immediately, but the new path is not a valid one.

```js
var d = d3.select(".nodes-path").attr("d");
d = d.replace(/\D/g, ",");
var dArray = d.split(",");
var newPath = "M " +
  dArray[0] +
  ", " +
  dArray[1] +
  ", " + //now I know it should be ", L " on this line
  dArray[dArray.length - 2] +
  ", " +
  dArray[dArray.length - 1];
d3.select(".nodes-path").attr("d", newPath);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="200 200 600 600">
  <path d="M 547, 699 C 547, 759 347, 236, 347, 296" class="nodes-path"></path>
</svg>
```

Reason for this is that you replace *everything but numbers* with commas, but then there are also duplicate subsequent commas. I can split the path using regex into the MoveTo part and the Bezier Curve, and then append the final parts like this:

```js
var d = d3.select(".nodes-path").attr("d");
// First, just get the start of the path in one piece
var start = d.substr(0, d.indexOf("C"));
var dArray = d.split(",");
var newPath = start +
  "L" +
  dArray[dArray.length - 2] +
  ", " +
  dArray[dArray.length - 1];
d3.select(".nodes-path").attr("d", newPath);
```

```css
path {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="200 200 600 600">
  <path d="M 547, 699 C 547, 759 347, 236, 347, 296" class="nodes-path"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: You are right. But for some reason i can't achieve same result. I get nothing from attr("d"). I'm using this code in react useEffect hook, but it shouldn't matter, as I can easily access other attributes of this node, like class and they show up in console just fine. Moreover, even if i hardcode new path, attr("d", newPath) doesn't update it

Comment: Could it be a timing issue where `d` hasn't been set yet? So `useEffect` is called before your rendering function?

Comment: yes, svg haven't finished drawing at the moment i've been trying to update path. Setting timeout did the trick, and used your code, and it worked. If only there was a way to add event listener to svg so it updates the moment svg finishes it's drawing. but that's different problem, thanks for your help! :)